# Find all the values of $x$ for $x^2-px+20=0, x^2-20x+p=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find all the values of $x$ satisfying the pair of equations
>
> $$x^2-px+20=0, {\hspace 20pt}x^2-20x+p=0$$

Solving the equations simultaneously we get $x=-1$, ***is this correct?***

Consider, 
${\hspace 20pt}x^2-9x+20=0, {\hspace 20pt}x^2-20x+9=0$

First eq gives $x=5, x=4 $,
2nd eq gives $x=10\pm \sqrt{91}$

Comment: $p=20x-x^2$, $x^2-(20x-x^2)x+20=0$, and so on.

Comment: `Consider ...` Those two equations don't have a common root, so they don't help with the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is almost correct.

If you have some $x$ that satisfies the two, then you can subtract them, which gives us

$$(20 - p)x + (20 -p) = 0$$

This implies $x = -1$ or $20 = p$. You need to consider both cases.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you equated $x^2$ from both equations, leading to something like $ -px+20 = -20x+p$. Moving $x$ terms to one side and constants to the other, you get $(20-p)(x)=(20-p)(-1)$, and you reached the conclusion $x$ has to be -1. Think carefully. Did you just divide by zero? Is it not possible that $p=20$? What are the other possible values of $x$ now?